# how to give colors for pie chart result in apex dashboard, I have given the query used inside pie chart series

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, apexcharts

How to give colors for pie chart  result in apex dashboard, I have given the query used inside pie chart series

For ex: If status is Approved then show the result in green color, if rejected then show in red color, if Pending then show-result in yellow color

Below is the query used inside pie chart region:

```
SELECT sum(cheque_amount) tot_Amt,
CASE
    WHEN status='Approved' THEN status
    WHEN status='Rejected' THEN status 
    WHEN status='Pending' THEN status  
END AS STATUS`enter code here`
FROM PDC_CHEQUES 
group by status
```

Comment: I don't know about pie chart to you have mentioned but what are you trying to do with the query ? The case statement is doing nothing. By the way you didn't say what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a column in your query define the colour you need, say

```
,case 
when status = 'Approved' then 'u-color-5'
when status = 'Rejected' then 'u-color-9'
end as col_colour
```

Then map that column to the colour attribute in the chart attributes, where you map the other columns.

These colours are defined in the [UT application](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/color-and-status-modifiers).

Comment: Thank @Scott, i have modified my code as ur suggestion,now color is changing as required but the name of the pie showing as ,ex: for Approved its showing as ''u-color-5'' same for others,please suggest 

SELECT sum(cheque_amount) tot_Amt,
    case  when status = 'Approved' then 'u-color-5'
              when status = 'Rejected' then 'u-color-9'
              when status = 'Pending'  then 'u-warning'
    end as status
FROM PDC_CHEQUES
group by status

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to an APEX 5.1 environment as your tags suggest, but in my APEX 19.2 environment, when creating a Chart region that is set up to use the Pie Oracle Jet chart, you can specify the Hex number or HTML color code that the section should be. If you define a column in your SQL query that defines the color, you can reference it in the **Color** field using the **&COLUMN_NAME.** syntax.

[image]

[image]